# Partial view is not updating image in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view on which two partial views are rendered.One partial view(lstContactPerson) contains the List of contacts(image and other details) and action buttons for View/Edit/Delete.On Edit button-click details of a record is rendered in another partial view(Contact) for edit. After submitting Contact form the details are updated but not an image on lstContactPerson view without reloading the page.

I have searched for this and found that issue must be of caching and i implemented most of cache removing/Disabling stuff but issue is not resolved.

Comment: Show us some code please.

Answer (score 0):

try adding some random value to image url. it will ensure that image is not fetched from browsers cache

```
http://yourimage.png?nocache={GUID}
```